# Convertion of JSON payload and parsing it in ESQL

Tags: json

See,
I am getting certain response from backend and its inside my tree forming after passing through a common subflow is in JSON format. Like:

```
XMLNSC
    Error
            Header
                    Application:CHARACTER:IBM WebSphere Message Broker 12080
                    BrokerName:CHARACTER:integration_server
                    BrokerOperatingSystem:CHARACTER:WINDOWS
                    MessageFlowName:CHARACTER:MF_ABC
                    ExecutionGroupName:CHARACTER:ABC
                    ProcessIdentifier:INTEGER:19216
                    CreationTimestamp:CHARACTER:2001-03-09 10:13:35.000
                    Type:CHARACTER:FAILURE
            SourceDetails
            Message
                    CHARACTER:{"status":"failed","message":"Malformed request","errorsCount":1,"errors":[{"path":"#/CustomerInformation","message":"Missing required property: Name"}]}
```

The value that I am using is in the 'Message' Tree and I am unable to parse it further.

Logic I have used:

```
SET Environment.Variables.JSON.Data.Message = InputRoot.XMLNSC.Error.Message.Item[1].* ;
SET Environment.Variables.JSON.Data.Message1.Item[1].Item = InputRoot.XMLNSC.Error.Message ;
```

I need it to traverse through the whole payload but no able to do it.

I expect to traverse through the paylaod coming in 'Message' and use the JSON.

Comment: Solution:     
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.JSON.Data AS jsonInputRef PARSE(InputRoot.XMLNSC.Error.Message CCSID 1208);                                  This way JSON tree gets created like this : OutputRoot
 Properties
   CodedCharSetId:CHARACTER:1208
 MQMD
   Format:CHARACTER:MQSTR
 JSON
   Data
     JSON
       Data
         status:CHARACTER:failed
         message:CHARACTER:Malformed request
         errorsCount:INTEGER:1
         errors
           Item
             path:CHARACTER:#/connectionInformation
             message:CHARACTER:Missing required property: customerIP